# Foursquare API nearByVenue service issue

Tags: ios, google-maps, gps, foursquare

Using Foursquare API "Venue" service.. I am parsing `nearByVenue` details like shop, restaurant etc.

Suppose as an example I am getting following link:

```
https://api.foursquare.com/v1/venues.json?geolat=40.562362&geolong=-111.938689
```

Issue is I am getting only 10 `nearbyDetails`.. suppose I am standing in New York there should be number of venue details.. why I am getting only 10 details only?

Is there any other service or I am following wrong approach to use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `l=n` where n is your limit in query string. The default limit is set to 30.

```
https://api.foursquare.com/v1/venues.json?geolat=40.562362&geolong=-111.938689&l=10
```

Comment: you know of a way to sort them by importance or other features? like if i want to get only grocery stores. also pagination... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

https://api.foursquare.com/v1/venues.xml?geolat=40.562362&geolong=-111.938689&l=50&q=coffee

You can change the value of l="no of result" parameter.

And also if you want to search for particular keyword like ATM, Coffee
then you can add the parameter q and add it's value like q="atm", q="coffee", etc.

hope it will be helpful to you.